# Replacing PHP condition with row value from database

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, conditional-statements

PHP code:

```
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM `calculations`") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
while($parts = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $apples = "yellow";
    $a = 1;
    $b = 2;
    if($parts['part_condition'])
    {
        echo $parts['part_if_true'] . "<br>";
    } else
    {
        echo $parts['part_if_false'] . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Database:
[image]

Please observe my code. I am trying to get the condition from `part_condition` column and echo results from `part_if_true` and `part_if_false` tables, but it does not work. It only returns me values from `part_if_true` column.

I need this code to create an universal code for a few hundreds of conditions.

Am I getting close by doing this?

For id 1 the result should be:
**False**

For id 2:
**'A is smaller than B'**

For id 3:
**False**

I need to do this in order for the user to edit and create conditions.

Comment: Why do people put their business logic in a database (outside of any kind of version control) and then expect to execute it in PHP?

Comment: so, where are you using `$a` and `$b`? and why are you storing `a>b` and `a<b` and other one? Your model/logic is all wrong.

Comment: I need the user to create the conditions in an admin panel.

Comment: And why does some logic have `$` (`$apples = "red"`) values and other not (`a>b`)? That looks inconsistent

Comment: @Fred-ii- variables are in while loop.

Comment: I honestly don't understand what you're trying to do here, and with what you stored in your columns. Sorry, but I'll have to pass on this one.

Comment: Basically you're going to have to write your own parser, to convert that condition to PHP code that can be evaluated, problems arise with inconsistencies like the aforementioned `$` and also with `=` for omparison

Comment: It's always going to output `echo $parts['part_if_true']` because your if statment;  `if($parts['part_condition'])` returns true, all the time. Because it always has a value in the database..

Comment: @MarkBaker I need the user to create his own conditions.

Comment: There is a php function called eval() but it is discouraged.  But it can read string values as php statements. http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: @WillParky93 I know that. I need to adjust the code in order to follow the condition from db.

Comment: @Dean Thank you. The most useful answer that helped so far. Now I know that I need a parser.

Comment: How complex can these formulae get? Can there be multiple comparisons, with AND/OR logic as well? Or are they always simple x compared with y type conditions? If the latter, then better to store as varA, varB and comparison operator.... you can avoid the harder parsing then, and avoid the use of eval (which breaks very easily)

Comment: @MarkBaker it can be like: `if($something == '' && $something != '' && $something > 0)`

Comment: That's significantly complex then, there's no easy solution, but at least it's just && and not || as well.... how comfortable are you with OO code?

Comment: And can you enforce consistency with whether your users use $ or not?

Comment: @MarkBaker I am and I can manage. Need to find a solution, otherwise, the user should learn to code and I don`t want that.

Comment: @MarkBaker I can assure that users will create the good conditions. They will have a legend.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156846/discussion-between-mark-baker-and-bogdan-c).

Comment: @BogdanC, you might consider having another table in your database of predefined conditions and then a foreign key field that references those conditions.

Comment: @Dean Most likely I will do that. Thank you.